# Jira Server 8.5.8 - Wiki Style Renderer custom field - Set default table using Behaviour Initialiser

Tags: groovy, server, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-agile

I have a Wiki Style Renderer custom field named "My Custom Field" ID = 12345678

I would like to set as default value a small table (2 headers + 2 empty rows):

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IMwe.png)

Is it possible? In case behaviour is not optional I am open for more ideas.
I will appreciate in case someone has the full code to the solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click the "Text" menu under that Wiki-Style field, you will see a text representation of the table; something like that:

```
|| Heading 1 || Heading 2 ||
|| || ||
|| || ||
```

Copy that value and just set it in the behaviour. You can use that script for the following operation:

```
def theTableValue = "..." // Table value from above
def theField = getFieldById("customfield_<your wiki field's id>") // i.e customfield_10000

theField.formValue = theTableValue
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your answer!!! :-)

Comment: Happy to hear that :) Please up-vote and accept the answer if it works; so if any user face with the same issue; he/she can access that correct answer.